# Android 4.2.1 - Operating System Storage is occupying too much space

Tags: applications, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, operating-system

Dunno if this is a proper question to ask here, my problem is about the storage of my android on the internal memory. I have 16gigs of sd card, 16 gigs internal storage as well, but I am seeing this on my android's storage settings:

[image]

It looks so weird and I cant install apps, even though I choose sdcard for storage/installation location.

The brand is Coolpad 8903, possibly not on sale anywhere out of China, but this looks like os issue i suppose...

anyone knows how to fix this problem so i can free some storage?

Comment: So, your problem here is that for whatever reason, the device manufacturers put the /data mountpoint on the /system parition and kept the /sdcard partition seperate. Usually, /data lives on /sdcard. Your options at this point are to try to see if you can resize the partitions (hard), or use an app-to-sdcard solution. What version of Android are you using?

Comment: 4.2.1, jelly bean i suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best solution would be to "root" your device (See [here](http://lifehacker.com/5789397/the-always-up-to-date-guide-to-rooting-any-android-phone) if you don't know what rooting is). Basically "rooting" your phone will give you permission to do anything on your phone. You might find it strange but currently, you are not allowed to do many things with your phone even if you own it :)

Anyways, getting back to the point. You can do the following things to make life easier for you:-

1. Remove some of the pre-installed applications which you don't use:- After rooting, you will be able to remove pre-installed applications. Remove all of them which you don't use. You can use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) for this purpose.
2. Integrate update of pre-installed apps:- Some of these pre-installed applications (including Google applications such as Gmail, Play Store, Chrome, etc.) receive an update at a later point of time. When they get updated, their old version doesn't get removed. They are still taking up space. After rooting you will be able to integrate the update so that older copies get actually replaced by new versions. You can use same Titanium Backup for this also.
3. Move as many apps as possible to SD card:- After rooting, you will be able to move any application to sd card. Again, Titanium backup to your help.

Comment: I know what rooting means, and already removed some pre installed apps from my phone :) I was able to free the space by removing some Google Play-like apps (I am in China and we have nice rules about accessing Google services :D ) and got 300+ MB space on the phone, though the OS occupation remains the same... But for permanent solution I need to root it totally I guess...

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by a more permanent solution. Since you are already rooted, you can move ANY app to sd card. So for you it doesn't matter how much space your OS is taking. Although you can try re-partitioning but i would recommend that as a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

That device is partitioned very oddly.  It looks like they took 4GB and left it to device storage, and then the other 12GB are partitioned for an internal SD card.

That's about the correct size that the Android system would be using - but what is troubling is that they only left ~1GB or so for user-installable applications.  I doubt there are any ROMs or recoveries available for your device, so I think the best solution would be to move as many applications as you can over to your SD card, therefore freeing up space to download more (and then subsequently move them as well).

Answer (score 1):

Well, there isn't many option available for you, can either root your device and install some other custom ROM over your device which may be less bulky, or you can try removing more application to free up some more space out of your device. Now rest I'll leave it to you !

Answer (score 0):

As I have tried and succeeded this method, am giving you a suggestion with my experience. All the applications you installed, may be moved to SD card, but 75-80% of the app data will remain in the phone itself. Maximum part of the app will be in phone memory. Try to uninstall the unwanted applications, even though if you have moved to SD card.